# please, why doesn't this sql update query work?

Tags: php, sql

```
//my update query
$query = "UPDATE articles SET
        title='$title',
        author='$author',
        body='$body'
        WHERE id = {$uid}";
```

Error

> ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Now, I using mysqli extension with PHP.

Comment: I have removed the 2 `\`enter code here\`` Woopsies for you I assume they were not in the real code

Comment: I would have a guess that `$uid` value is empty.  Although prepared statements will help with both SQL injection, but also sometimes solve odd problems like this (well at least help).

Comment: ^^^ ___Debugging___ `var_dump($uid);` and check what you have in there

Comment: @NigelRen  $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: And if `$_POST['uid']` is empty then `$uid` will also be empty Did you first check that `$_POST['uid']` was set??

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST);` and check what is ACTUALLY in that array

Comment: Dear guys, I did uid input like that <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php $post['id']; ?>">

Comment: Sorry Dear helpers, I just found my crazy error. Cause echo let in value element. Thank you all.